# How to bind data from ascx.cs page to ascx page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I got some bunch of data from a service and deserialized and kept in variable 'StoreDetails' like below.

```
var StoreDetails= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Info.Wrapper>(json);
```

Sample data what StoreDetails contain is:

```
{"Status":{"StatusCode":200,"StatusDisplay":"OK","StatusValue":true,"Version":2},"Store":[{"Carry Out":false,"Coupons":true,"CustomURL":"https:\/\/ordering.com\/5702\/locations\/7725","DeliveryAvailable":false,"Distance":1.05,"Drive Thru":false,"FranchiseStoreId":0000002,"HasPromotion":false,"}]
```

I want to pull this data from ascx.cs page to ascx page. I know how to pull data in cshtml page using model like below, but I'm now sure in aspx to pull data.

Eaxample:

```
<h4>@Model.Store.ShortAdd.Address1</h4>
<h6>@Model.Store.ShortAdd.Address2</h6>
```

Can someone help me to pull data and display in a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you can use **Literal** control to pass plain data *(without additional markup)* from Code Behind.

### ASPX

```
<h4><asp:Literal runat="server" ID="Address1Literal" /></h4>
```

### Code Behind

```
protected void Page_Load(object source, EventArgs e)
{
    Address1Literal.Text = "Some text";
}
```

[You can even pass JSON data directly to script tag](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39881014/296861).

Comment: I have almost like 20 variables I need to bring from .cs page and display in html page. Do you want me to declare literal for each html element I write? Can I use GridView to bring complete data like GridView1.DataSource = StoreInfo; GridView1.DataBind();

Comment: You can use GridView as long as you do not plan to use those data inside script tag at client-side. Based on your question, it seems like you want to pass JSON from code behind to ASPX page.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign the data to a literal or label or hidden field on ascx.cs and used that in ascx page.

Answer (score 0):

You can use various controls for show json data in user control. For example you can use `GridView` like this:

**ascx**

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvJsonData" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Visible="true">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Code" HeaderText="Code" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Questions" HeaderText="Questions" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

**ascx.cs**

```
string JsonData = "[{'Code':'S1','Questions':'Q1,Q2'}" + "," + "{'Code':'S2','Questions':'Q3,Q4,Q5'}]";
var Students = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(JsonData);
gvJsonData.DataSource = Students;
gvJsonData.DataBind();
```

**Output**

[image: gvJsonData]